# Custom CSS Cursor not working in some areas?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I am trying to challenge myself in my html/css class by adding a custom cursor to all pages.

I have it working, but it seems to randomly stop being the custom cursor, and become the default instead?

The css I'm using for it:

```
* { 
cursor: url("image.gif") 33 33, auto; 
}
```

I have also tried using `<span>` for entire html documents, and that is not fixing it either for me.

I have also tried setting the cursor in
body{} and it didn't fix it.

Any help would be appreciated! I googled and searched the site for over 2 hours trying to find an answer that would work.

Posting the site below so you can see what I mean. (IE won't show the cursor, not sure about safari or opera yet)

http://www.rvertbleu.com/2014fa/dbrown/index.html

EDIT:

Made a shorter version of my index.html and my main.css that recreates the problem. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Gundam Base</title>

</head>


<body bgcolor="#000000">


<h1><center>Gundam Base</center></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

main.css

```
* {
   cursor: url("gundam.gif") 33 33, auto;

}



body {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-size:1.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #CC3300;
    background-image:url('bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -5000;
    background-attachment: scroll
    background-color: black;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that that is the correct path to the image 'image.gif'? Did you perhaps put the image in an image folder and forget to update the code? This code appears to be from a CSS file, in which case your path should either be '../image.gif' or '../images/image.gif'

Comment: Works for me ... as an fyi the eye-glow image that appears on hovering the menus should be a PNG to give you an alpha channel.

Comment: @Fribetarian Yeah I don't really know the "standards" for this kinda thing, my main.css is in the topmost folder with my index.html.

Comment: Sorry new to stack overflow (this is my first post), but why was my question down-voted? Did I break a rule?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Alright edited it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a div after the body tag with the following styles position: relative; width: 100%; min-height: 600px;cursor: url("gundam.gif"), auto;:

place all your other content in the above div. let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, no luck to be had with that one. I only have one thing after body and thats my glow class, and adding that to it didn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: your cursor was working fine in safari and  chrome only in firefox it was fluctuating… when i added this div through inspect element it started working perfectly for me in firefox

Comment: This fixed it, but because position was set to relative, it moves my eye glow, but I think this is better then nothing! Definitely the best answer.